# The "show" page isn't displaying the property of the correct data

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I'm making a website using ror and I have a list of fandoms, and I want to display different pictures and writing for that fandom. Right now, just for testing, I'm having it just display the name of the fandom at the top of the page, but no matter which one I click on, it only displays the name of the first fandom. Here's the parts of the files I think are relevant, but if you need to see more, I'll post it.

Section of routes.rb:

```
get 'fandoms' => 'fandoms#index'
get 'fandoms/new' => 'fandoms#new'
post 'fandoms' => 'fandoms#create'
get 'fandoms/:id' => 'fandoms#show', as: :fandom
resources :fandoms
```

The show method in fandoms_controller:

```
def show
    @fandom = Fandom.find_by(params[:id])
end
```

The index.html.erb for fandoms:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="container">
<h2>Fandoms</h2>
  <%= link_to "New Fandom (dev only)", "fandoms/new" %>
  <% @fandoms.each do |fandom| %>
  <div class="fandoms">
    <%= link_to fandom.name, fandom_path(fandom) %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

And finally the show.html.erb for fandoms:

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
  <h2>Fandoms</h2>
      <div class="fandom">
        <h1><%= @fandom.name %></h1>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I double checked my code with the Ror tutorial on codecademy, but I still couldn't find any differences for what I wanted to do.

Thanks.

Comment: so you are suggesting that on index page. what so ever fandom you click. it takes you to the show page of first fandom.?

Comment: No, it takes you to the correct one, but displays the wrong name. The three fandoms I have right now with the corresponding IDs (which are the ones used in the url) are

Doctor Who - 1
Supernatural - 2
Sherlock - 3

It takes me to the correct page, since I can see the URL is correct, but no matter what page I'm on, where the name is supposed to be, it always displays Doctor Who.

Comment: first of all please confirm me `@fandom = Fandom.find_by(params[:id])` this is in your code. should it be     `@fandom=Fandom.find_by_id(params[:id])` secondly i dont think it is possible that it is fetching correct fandom and shows different name. check your fandom controller show action where you are fetching fandom to see what is the id being passed to the fandom and the query it is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `show` action has a subtle typo that's breaking your logic:

```
@fandom = Fandom.find_by(params[:id])
```

Should actually be:

```
@fandom = Fandom.find(params[:id])
```

The difference is, `find_by` will return the first row for which the conditions passed are met. You're not actually passing any conditions; just an ID, which in Postgres doesn't even work:

```
irb> Fandom.find_by(1)
PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type integer
LINE 1: SELECT  "fandoms".* FROM "fandoms" WHERE (1) LIMIT 1
```

Your database is more permissive, but seems to be treating it just as a `WHERE TRUE` clause and thus every single row meets the condition. As such, it returns the first row every time. Using `find(id)` will give you the desired result.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I'll remember to use `find` in the future!